# How to update my local SQL Server database with the latest backup?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, backup

I'm using SQL Server 2012 in a local environment. In fact, it is running on my Windows 7 machine. My problem is as follows: I receive a daily backup of my SQL database. Right now, I'm just restoring the whole database on a daily basis by deleting the existing one. This restore task takes quite some time to complete. My understanding of the restore process is that it overwrites the previous database with the new backup. 
Is there a way for SQL Server 2012 to just modify the existing database with any changes that have occured in the new backup? I mean, something like comparing the previous database with the updated one and making the necessary changes where needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of a full backup you ill need a differential backup. Restore it to move to a "point in time" state of original database.
Make a basic research about full/differential and log backups (too many info for a short answer)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. You can do things with database replication, but that's probably not appropriate.

If you did have something to just pull out changes it might not be faster than a restore anyway. Are you a C# or similar dev? If so, I'd be tempted to write a service which monitored the location of the backup and start the restore programatically when it arrives; might save some time.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Can I merge changes from an external DB to my current DB without having to restore the whole DB?" then the answer is "Yes, but not easily."  You can set up log shipping, but that's fairly complicated to do automatically.  It's also fairly complicated to do manually, but for different reasons: there's no "Microsoft" way to do it.  You have to figure out manual log shipping largely on your own.

You could consider copying the tables manually via a Linked Server.  If you're only updating a small number of tables this might work just fine, and you could save yourself some trouble.  A linked server on your workstation, a few `MERGE` statements saved to a .sql file, and you could update the important tabled in the DB as you need to.

---

You *can* avoid having to run the full backup on the remote server by using differential backups, but it's not particularly pleasant.

My assumption is that currently you're getting a full backup created with the `COPY_ONLY` option.  This allows you to create an out-of-band backup copy that doesn't interfere with existing backups.

To do what you actually want, you'd have to do this:  on the server you set up backup to do a full backup on day 1, and then do differential backups on days 2-X.  Now, on your local system, you retain the full backup of the DB you created on day 1.  You then have all differential backups since day 1.  You restore the day 1 full DB, and then restore each subsequent differential in the correct order.

*However*, differential backups require the backup chain to be intact.  You can't use `COPY_ONLY` with a differential backup.  That means if you're also using backup to actually backup the database, you're going to either use these same backups for your data backups, or you'll need to have your data backups using `COPY_ONLY`, both of which seem philosophically wrong.  Your dev database copies shouldn't be driving your prod backup procedures.

So, you can do it, but:

1. You still have to do a full DB restore.
2. You have considerably more work to do to restore the DB.
3. You might break your existing backup procedures of the original DB.